# eslint /* exported functionName */ not working in browser env

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a few functions that are defined in one js file and used in others. They each have `/* exported functionName */` comments and I have my eslint env set to browser/jquery. Based on my reading of the [documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#exported) that's all I should need, but it doesn't seem to be working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's the .eslintrc (it extends [this one](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition-nodejs/blob/eslint-exported/.eslintrc), although I get the same behavior without the `extends`):

```
{
  "extends": "../../.eslintrc",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jquery": true
  }
}
```

And, here's one of the functions (here's the [second](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition-nodejs/blob/eslint-exported/public/js/use.js#L19) and [third](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition-nodejs/blob/eslint-exported/public/js/demo.js#L30)):

```
/**
 * Returns the next hour as Date
 * @return {Date} the next hour
 */
/* exported nextHour */
function nextHour() {
  var oneHour = new Date();
  oneHour.setHours(oneHour.getHours() + 1);
  return oneHour;
}
```

Finally, this is the output I get from eslint:

```
/Users/nfriedly/visual-recognition-nodejs/public/js/demo.js
  24:10  error  'nextHour' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  37:10  error  'resize' is defined but never used    no-unused-vars

/Users/nfriedly/visual-recognition-nodejs/public/js/use.js
  26:10  error  'setupUse' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

It works if I replace the `/* exported...` comment with an `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars` but I know that's not the correct solution.

You can check out the complete project from https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition-nodejs/tree/eslint-exported and then just run `npm install; npm test` if you want to see it for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the Babel-ESLint parser that the airbnb config specifies can override the parsing of config files to break the documented cascading behavior. Setting `"parser": null` resolves this.

Answer (score 0):

Your config states that you are working in Node environment. Node has an extra scope around every module, so global variables are not really possible in Node (at least not in the same way as in browser). As such, when `no-unused-vars` rule sees any environment with globalReturn flag on (Node, CommonJS, shared-node-browser) or modules on, it ignores `/* exported */` comments. You need to remove Node environment and enable browser environment if you want to use global variables and exported comments.

Comment: That's not the config that applies. (I removed the parent .eslintrc from the question to make it more clear which one is actually getting applied to this js) - the one in the same folder as the failing js sets the env to browser and jQuery.

Comment: if your parent config specifies node environment that means that it also applies to the current file (configs are deep merged, so if parent config specifies Node environment, it also applies to all child configs). As long as Node environment is enabled, `exported` will not work. You can run ESLint with `--print-config` flag to see exactly what configuration is used for a given file.

Comment: So you're saying there's no way to have a different config for a different js files?

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do that. For example you can add "root": true to the inner config file, and it will stop cascading configs (but then you don't get anything from the upper config files). You can also specify "Node": false in your inner config file, to turn off Node environment. I know there was a bug with that at some point, but I think it was fixed.